# build-wrapper stop at first git submodule

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I try to set up sonarqube for all my c++ projects. It works fine for all projects except one.

This project is the only one to have a submodule in the first place.
I have an src folder to analyze with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -sSLo build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip https://openshift.lumiplan.com/sonarqube/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip
unzip -o build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip
chmod +x build-wrapper-linux-x86/build-wrapper-linux-x86-64
build-wrapper-linux-x86/build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir bw-output make
ls
cat bw-output/build-wrapper-dump.json
cd ../../src
wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873-linux.zip
mkdir sonar-scanner
unzip sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873-linux.zip
ls
mv sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873-linux/* sonar-scanner/
rm sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
cp ../sonar-project.properties sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true -Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=../projects/linux-arm/bw-output -Dsonar.projectKey=products_panel_lumiplay-engine_AYKR3Op6FUISUZul32ck -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.login=14214a83196d3ae8f3507cff910c5da818e280a2 -Dsonar.host.url=https://openshift.lumiplan.com/sonarqube -Dsonar.branch.name=$1
```

but in src folder I have the following content:

- "api_asrcore" folder which is a git submodule
- "api_boost" folder which is a git submodule
- and all my code in different folders which is not git submodules

the logs:

```
NFO: Using 1 thread for analysis according to value of "sonar.cfamily.threads" property.
15:59:20  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/configuration_specific/source/configuration_specific.cpp at line 121 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
15:59:20  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/protocol/public/msg_plot_idbrndef.h at line 157 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
15:59:20  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/review/source/review_application_control.cpp at line 152 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
15:59:20  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/protocol/source/msg_plot_idbrndef.cpp at line 579 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
15:59:20  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/decodage/source/decodage_plot.cpp at line 294 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
15:59:20  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/decodage/public/decodage_plot.h at line 164 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
INFO: PCH: unique=0 use=0 (forceInclude=0,throughHeader=0,firstInclude=0) out of 0 (forceInclude=0,throughHeader=0)
15:59:20  INFO: SE: 0 out of 0
15:59:20  INFO: Z3 refutation rate: 0 out of 0
15:59:20  INFO: Subprocess(es) done in 46ms
15:59:20  INFO: 0 compilation units analyzed
15:59:20  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:59:20  INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
15:59:20  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:59:20  INFO: Total time: 48.891s
15:59:20  INFO: Final Memory: 63M/220M
15:59:20  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:59:20  ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
15:59:20  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The "build-wrapper-dump.json" file was found but 0 C/C++/Objective-C files were analyzed.
```

in other projects there is at least one folder which is not a git submodule before "api_asrcore" in the following example there is an "action_manager" and an "annoncesonore_html" folders before submodules

logs:

```
INFO: Using 1 thread for analysis according to value of "sonar.cfamily.threads" property.
14:49:17  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/decodage/source/decodage_plot.cpp at line 310 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
14:49:17  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/protocol/source/msg_plot_idbrndef.cpp at line 632 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
14:49:17  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/protocol/public/msg_plot_idbrndef.h at line 165 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
14:49:17  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/decodage/public/decodage_plot.h at line 166 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
14:49:17  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/synchronisation/source/synchronisation.cpp at line 68 for encoding UTF-8. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
14:49:17  WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /usr/src/lumiplan/src/specific/configuration_specific/source/configuration_specific.cpp at line 216 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
14:49:17  WARN:
14:49:17  CFamily plugin supports incremental analysis with the use of a cache:
14:49:17  
14:49:17  * if you do not want to enable cache
14:49:17  please explicitly disable it
14:49:17  by setting the following property to your analysis:
14:49:17  sonar.cfamily.cache.enabled=false
14:49:17  
14:49:17  * to enable cache please specify the following 2 options:
14:49:17  sonar.cfamily.cache.enabled=true
14:49:17  sonar.cfamily.cache.path=relative_or_absolute_path_to_cache_location
14:49:17  
14:49:17  * visit the documentation page for more information
14:49:17  https://openshift.lumiplan.com/sonarqube/documentation/analysis/languages/cfamily/
14:49:17  
14:49:17  INFO: [pool-3-thread-1] /usr/src/lumiplan/projects/linux-arm/../../src/specific/action_manager/source/action_handler.cpp
14:49:17  INFO: [pool-3-thread-1] /usr/src/lumiplan/projects/linux-arm/../../src/specific/annoncesonore_html/sources/annoncesonore.cpp
14:49:17  INFO: PCH: unique=0 use=0 (forceInclude=0,throughHeader=0,firstInclude=0) out of 2 (forceInclude=0,throughHeader=0)
14:49:17  INFO: SE: 2 out of 2
14:49:17  INFO: Z3 refutation rate: 0 out of 3
```

in this case the sonar analysis are complete do you know why? (there are no specific sonar-project.properties in both cases)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my strategy. I have created my bash script to get all submodules paths and I have added it to sonar.exclusions path (using

`$(git submodule foreach 'a=$(printf "$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --full-name|sed "s~^~$(pwd)/~")"; printf x); a=${a%x}; echo "$a"' | sed '/^\s*$/d')`

command). So all submodule has to vérify it's own code quality instead of the main project.